# heroku crashes with JSON error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku

I am going through the [rails tutorial from railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec%3adeploying) and I have hit a stumbling block.

My versions are thus:

- ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel
  334) [i386-mingw32]
- Rails 3.0.4
- heroku 1.18.2
- sqlite3 3.7.3
- git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0

I get this error when I run any heroku command (heroku create, heroku keys:add etc.)

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.5.1-x86-mingw32/lib/js
on/ext/parser.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
```

I noticed that some people were talking about incompatibility between heroku and json, so I uninstalled json 1.5.1 and installed json 1.4.6 instead.

I then get the error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:861:in `report_ac
tivate_error': RubyGem version error: json(1.4.6 not ~> 1.5.1) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:255:
in `activate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:290:
in `activate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:289:
in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:289:
in `activate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1204
:in `gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/heroku:18
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether to answer this myself, as the problem has not actually been resolved, but [I got onto Heroku](https://support.heroku.com/requests/20202) and they asked me to try the previous version using this code:

```
gem install heroku --pre
```

So it seems to be a bug in the latest version of the gem (?)